# display index of canvas charts

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I have a chart like following ,made using canvasjs

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
{
    title:{
        text: "Attaching Click event on first Column",
    },
    data: [
    {
        type: "column",
        dataPoints: [
          { label:"A", y: 71, click: onClick },
            { label:"B", y: 55 },
            { label:"C", y: 50 },
            {label:"D", y: 65 },
            { label:"E", y: 95 },
            { label:"F", y: 68 },
            { label:"G", y: 28 },
            { label:"H", y: 34 },
            { label:"I", y: 14 }
        ]
    }
    ]
   });
   chart.render();

    function onClick(e){
    alert(  e.dataSeries.type+ ", dataPoint {y: "+ e.dataPoint.y + " }"                                                    ) ;   
}
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

all i want to do now is to do show the Label in the alert ,but i can't find the event object for it.Does an event object for label or any other chart entity even exist?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Solution](http://jsbin.com/vobix/1/edit)

The info you want is at:

```
e.dataPoint.label
```

Comment: thanks a lot , I did try the same but i must have been messing up with something .Thanks a lot again!